# JQuery: Want to Select Only 3 Checkboxes at a time and I want them to also Enable/Disable a input box

Tags: jquery

I have this sort of working:

Basically, I want to Have 6 checkboxes and 6 inputs, and when you click on a checkbox, it will then enable the input to allow the user to enter data. And when you uncheck the checkbox, it will disable the input field. Also, I only want 3 to be selected, the rest will be disabled.

```
<div class="span5 lengthcontainer">
                    <label class="control-label">Lengths:</label>
                    <div class="row day-selection">

                        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="LCheckbox" >
                        <label>:05&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        <input name="textinput" type="text" class="input-mini-length LInput" disabled>

                        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="LCheckbox">
                        <label>:10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        <input id="10Input" name="textinput" type="text" class="input-mini-length LInput" disabled>

                        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="LCheckbox" >
                        <label>:15&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="input-mini-length LInput" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row day-selection">
                                            <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="LCheckbox" >
                        <label>:30&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="input-mini-length LInput" disabled>

                        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="LCheckbox" >
                        <label>:60&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="input-mini-length LInput" disabled>

                        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="LCheckbox">
                        <label>:60+</label>
                        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="input-mini-length LInput" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>

 //Enables only 3 at a time for Unit Lengths section in the advertiser wizard
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.LCheckbox').click(function(){
if($('input.LCheckbox').filter(':checked').length == 3)
    $('input.LCheckbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
else
    $('input.LCheckbox').removeAttr('disabled');
 });
 });

$(document).ready(function () {
$('.LCheckbox').change(function(){
if ($('input.LCheckbox').is(':checked') == true){
  $(this).nextAll(".LInput:first").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    $(this).nextAll(".LInput:first").val("").prop('disabled', true);

    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce all that to:

```
$('.LCheckbox').click(function () {
    $(this).next().next().prop('disabled', !this.checked)
    $('.LCheckbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', $('.LCheckbox:checked').length == 3);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D5wzn/1)**

Comment: Why not cache `$(this)`, and -if not- why not simply use `!this.checked`? I'm assuming for simplicity and the 'jQuery way' (but given the motive behind jQuery is "write less, do more" using `is()` doesn't seem efficient...).

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient version of what I posted:
Change your javascript to be:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('.LCheckbox').click(function(){
      $('.LCheckbox').not(':checked').prop('disabled', $('.LCheckbox:checked').length == 3);
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    $(this).nextAll(".LInput:first").prop('disabled', !isChecked)
    if ( ! isChecked ) {
       $(this).nextAll(".LInput:first").val("");    
    }

 });
 });
```

Here is a fiddle of it working [http://jsfiddle.net/SwdFg/](http://jsfiddle.net/SwdFg/2/)